# Unable to Add Multiple scopes in google apis request using PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-workspace

I am working on google apis and accessing google drives calendars etc ,while requesting single scope i.e google sheets or docs it is working fine but unable to set multiple scopes in single request.

I tried various things as discussed on other forums like added multiple like
added multiple scopes with comma sepration

`$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR,Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);`

also created new array like

`$scopes=['Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR','Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE']`

but none worked for me

this is my code

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR,Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig('simplo_other_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Is the json correctly generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no PHP expert, but...

According to examples, the setScopes method can indeed accept an array of scopes as an argument. See: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/Google_Client/setScopes/php-google_client-setscopes-method-examples.html

Your example code shows that you did attempt to pass in an array, but you wrapped **Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR** and **Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE** in single quotes, which would turn those into strings and not references to the values they represent.